# In wordpress new products do not appear with wpbakery Only the old ones that appear

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpbakery

When adding a new product or post through the wpbakery page on WordPress it does not appear at all, but only old products appear, and this is through the plugin tool: Tours Grid:
Whereas, I can only see new products when using Woocommerce
But the old ones don't appear with Woocommerce
Also, I was not able to display more than 3 products per row using Woocommerce ..

It is worth noting that the changes occurred after the update to 5.5
WordPress was version 5.5 while wpbakery was 1.3.8
Woocommerce is 4.4.1
Any advice